# Phaser JS how to stop event Propagation(firing) from textButton.events.onInputDown event to game.input.onDown event?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/g05bbL6g/2/)**.

I have two events here.

1. Is **`game.input.onDown`** which does some logic (generates particles in my example)
2. Is **`textButton.events.onInputDown`**, where textButton is a **[Phaser.Text](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Text.html)** object instance, which does another logic.

The problem is: when I click on my **textButton** both event are fired **1** and **2**.

The question is, how to prevent event **1** from firing when I click on the **textButton**?

Part of code:

```
...
//This event is fired on click anywhere event # 1
game.input.onDown.add(particleBurst, this);

//This is Clickable text
textButton = game.add.text(game.world.width - 5, 5, "CLICK ME", fontStyle);
textButton.anchor.setTo(1, 0);
textButton.inputEnabled = true;

//This event is fired on click on text event # 2
textButton.events.onInputDown.add(function () {
    console.log("button is Clicked");
}, this, 2);
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a background - transparent sprite - and use `input.priorityID`.

> The priorityID is used to determine which game objects should get
>   priority when input events occur. For example if you have several
>   Sprites that overlap, by default the one at the top of the display
>   list is given priority for input events. You can stop this from
>   happening by controlling the priorityID value. The higher the value,
>   the more important they are considered to the Input events.

See: http://docs.phaser.io/InputHandler.js.html#sunlight-1-line-45

```
// This is event #1 added to background sprite
var bg = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
bg.fixedToCamera = true;
bg.scale.setTo(game.width, game.height);
bg.inputEnabled = true;
bg.input.priorityID = 0; // lower priority
bg.events.onInputDown.add(particleBurst);
```

Make sure your textButton has higher priority:

```
textButton.input.priorityID = 1; // higher pirority
```

Add the clicked sprite (our background) as a first parameter to the particle function:

```
function particleBurst(bg, pointer) {
```

This way only one event should be triggered.

Check out modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g05bbL6g/3/

Comment: Thank you @lpiepiora. This definitely works, IMHO as a pretty good workaround. However I wonder if there is any solution for global game input? As I tried my own priority does not work in that case.

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants I don't know of better way, if there is I would gladly get to know it myself ;)